# How to fire click event on already-selected OptionButton in Excel Userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform, radio-button

I read somewhere that once an option button (or radio button) is selected on a UserForm, click events are not registered. Is this true?

If so, what are some good ways around this, aside from using checkboxes instead?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Per user3561813's suggestion, I tried the MouseUp event with the following code:

`Private Sub myOptionButton_MouseUp()
    MyUserForm.Show
End Sub`

I received this compile error: "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

UPDATE 2: This code does not work to allow unselection of already-selected radio button:

`Private Sub myOptionButton_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If myOptionButton.Value = True Then
        myOptionButton.Value =  False
    Else
        myOptionButton.Value = True
    End If
End Sub`

Oddly, if I step-through the code, it DOES work. But if I just run it through, it DOES NOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MouseUp` event to run whichever code you like.

Comment: brilliant idea. Maybe I'm just having trouble executing, but I'm getting the following `Compile Error: "Procedure declaration does not match description of event of procedure having the same name"`. See update above for the code.

Comment: @AlexSilverman I believe you receive that error because the event method is not properly declared. The `MouseUp` event take a number of parameters. The declaration line should read as: `Private Sub OptionButton1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. Sorry I can only upvote once

Comment: See UPDATE 2, for new modified question!

Answer (score -1):

Probably a little too late, but for Update 2, should you use something like

```
Controls(myOptionButton).Value = False
```

to change the value, therefore,

```
If myOptionButton.Value = True Then
    Controls(myOptionButton).Value =  False
Else
    Controls(myOptionButton).Value = True
End If
```

Comment: Using this code for click event, the option button never enters selected state. :(